# How to Add contacts to Windows Live Mail using C#

Tags: c#, windows, email, live

Am writing an application to add contacts to windows Live mailbut i cant find any document on that. And also i dont know if is the same as the outlook....Cant find even the dll for that

Thanks hope someone can help

Comment: I am looking for the same.. Any luck??